# Install asp.net mvc 2 beta on Visual Studio 2010 Beta2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2010

Is there any workaround on installing asp.net mvc 2 beta on a VS2010 Beta2 box?. Phil said on his post that it isn't supported for VS2010 beta2, mostly because of the tooling support and stuff...

But what If I just reference the DLL??!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the blog post you mention, scroll down and you'll see a workaround posted in the comments.  Direct link: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/asp.net-mvc-2-beta-released.aspx#74907